# Subsetting within for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

I am working on a fuzzy matching script in R.
In this I need to subset data frames for each country in a list and then do the matching countrywise.
However, my knowledge of loops in R is rather low.

This script should return the subset of each country in the afrocountrylist.
Any suggestions on how to make this subsetting work?

Thanks!

```
afrobaro <- data.frame(country=rep(c("Benin","Uganda","Mali"),each=5), 
                   region=c("Benind1","Benin2","Benins3","Benina4","Benin5",
                            "Ugandat1","Ugandar2","Ugandae3","Uganda4","Uganda5",
                            "Mali1r","Mali2","Malig3","Mali4","Mali5"))

jaroloop <- function(afrobaro, afrocountry,afroregion){
  afrocountrylist <- as.vector(unique(as.character(afrobaro[, afrocountry])))
  for(i in afrocountrylist){
    x <- afrocountrylist[i]
    print(x)
    afroregions <- subset(afrobaro, afrobaro$afrocountry == x)
    print(afroregions)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` to split a data frame along a vector:

```
res <- split(afrobaro, afrobaro$country)

# $Benin
#    country  region
# 1   Benin Benind1
# 2   Benin  Benin2
# 3   Benin Benins3
# 4   Benin Benina4
# 5   Benin  Benin5
# 
# $Mali
#    country region
# 11    Mali Mali1r
# 12    Mali  Mali2
# 13    Mali Malig3
# 14    Mali  Mali4
# 15    Mali  Mali5
# 
# $Uganda
#    country   region
# 6   Uganda Ugandat1
# 7   Uganda Ugandar2
# 8   Uganda Ugandae3
# 9   Uganda  Uganda4
# 10  Uganda  Uganda5
```

This returns a list with the three subsets. You can access the list elements (the subsets) with, e.g., `res$Benin` or `res[[1]]` for the first subset.

```
#   country  region
# 1   Benin Benind1
# 2   Benin  Benin2
# 3   Benin Benins3
# 4   Benin Benina4
# 5   Benin  Benin5
```

Once, you have the list of subsets, you can easily apply functions to each subset using `lapply`.

---

You can also use a `for` loop to extract all subsets:

```
for (i in unique(afrobaro$country)) {
  afroregions <- afrobaro[afrobaro$country == i, ]
  print(afroregions)
}
```

This prints all subsets. But note that `afroregions` is overwritten in each run. This is similar to you example code.

Comment: Thank you Sven! That is great, but I really would like to figure out how this works using a for loop as well.

Comment: @spesseh I added a solution with a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. It works fine. I so using $ in loops is ok. Will it also work in functions?